# django - refer to url name within settings.py

Tags: django, django-settings

My Django project's settings.py defines a few URL variables like `LOGIN_URL`, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, etc. My urls.py defines URLs with names ("acct_login", "acct_redirect", etc).

Is there some way I can refer to these urls inside settings.py **by name**? e.g. `LOGIN_URL = url(acct_login)`

Comment: Did you try [reverse() or reverse_lazy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [the `reverse()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse).

Comment: thanks! That works, but it turns up an issue later in settings.py, with `os.environ.get`